# Дать значение для scrollOverflow в fullpage после нажатие кнопки

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, fullpage

Нужно дать значение true для scrollOverflow после нажатие кнопки, Изначально у scrollOverflow значение false, а библиотека уже подгружена в html.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('#fullpage').fullpage({
        //Navigation
        menu: '#menu',
        lockAnchors: false,
        anchors: ['firstPage', 'secondPage'],
        navigation: true,
        navigationPosition: 'right',
        navigationTooltips: ['firstSlide', 'secondSlide'],
        showActiveTooltip: false,
        slidesNavigation: true,
        slidesNavPosition: 'bottom',

        //Scrolling
        css3: true,
        scrollingSpeed: 700,
        autoScrolling: true,
        fitToSection: true,
        fitToSectionDelay: 1000,
        scrollBar: false,
        easing: 'easeInOutCubic',
        easingcss3: 'ease',
        loopBottom: false,
        loopTop: false,
        loopHorizontal: true,
        continuousVertical: false,
        normalScrollElements: '#element1, .element2',
        scrollOverflow: false,
        touchSensitivity: 15,
        normalScrollElementTouchThreshold: 5,

        //Accessibility
        keyboardScrolling: true,
        animateAnchor: true,
        recordHistory: true,

        //Design
        controlArrows: true,
        verticalCentered: true,
        resize: false,
        sectionsColor: ['#ccc', '#fff'],
        paddingTop: '3em',
        paddingBottom: '10px',
        fixedElements: '#header, .footer',
        responsiveWidth: 0,
        responsiveHeight: 0,

        //Custom selectors
        sectionSelector: '.section',
        slideSelector: '.slide',

        //events
        onLeave: function(index, nextIndex, direction) {},
        afterLoad: function(anchorLink, index) {},
        afterRender: function() {},
        afterResize: function() {},
        afterSlideLoad: function(anchorLink, index, slideAnchor, slideIndex) {},
        onSlideLeave: function(anchorLink, index, slideIndex, direction, nextSlideIndex) {}
      });


      $('#show-more').on("click", function() {
        scrollOverflow = true;
      });
```

не смог запустить код((

Comment: а проблема в чем? вы хотите узнать, как запускать код?

Comment: $('#show-more').on("click", function() {
        scrollOverflow = true;
      });

Comment: Нужно изменить scrollOverflow на true, при нажатий на кнопку

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#show-more').on("click", function() {        
    $('#fullpage').fullpage({
        scrollOverflow: true
    });
});
```

Comment: несмотря на то, что синтаксически конструкция верна, она ничего не делает, так как в данном случае функция пустая, с меткой `scrollOverflow`

Comment: Так что мне написать внутри функций помогите пожалуйста

Comment: @Grundy да, затупил. поправил код в ответе

Comment: @lexxl, возможно стоит добавить описание или хотя бы ссылку на справку

Comment: спасибо вам все работает, только вот вчера этот же код не работал